# Demon's Soul - Where is the tutorial level, and are there two Gods?

Tags: dragons, demons-souls

Deep under the Stonefang Tunels, past the hall of the Firelurker, the Dragon God awaits in a deep cave for someone to face the fury of their fists.... or to turn them in a dragon kebab using the two nearby ballistae.

Jokes aside, the Dragon God boss in *Demon's Souls* is fought in the depths of an underground cave with no apparent exits. The creature is massive, far bigger than any other dragon seen in the game. It is really the God of Dragons. And... based on the comments from various NPCs in the game, it has been stuck down there for quite a while... to the point that few even remember its existence. It is safe to say that the Demon God can't leave the cave under Stonefang.

Yet again, for some players, Stonefang won't be the first time they see the Dragon God. Hidden right at the end of the very first (tutorial) location in the game, even before first setting foot in the Nexus, the Dragon God can be meet for a quick "punch you in the face during a cutscene" event.

This brings a question.
The building we traverse to meet the Dragon God in the tutorial is not the same we will fight in while in Stonefang. The area, the architecture, and the wall markings do not seem to match Stonefang. Yet again, the Stonefang Dragon should not be able to leave the cave...

So, where is the tutorial area located? Some suggest that a building can be seen on the opposite side of the cave, and that might be the location we visit in the tutorial, but this does not seem to be the case as the shape, size and about everything else in the cave do not seem to match anything we see in the tutorial (oddly enough though, the tutorial area contains two wooden ballistae.)

Everything seems to point to the existence of two separate "Dragon Gods" (for reference: this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9auUYZ5TOjY) shows the tutorial god from multiple angles) - even the ending of the game contains artwork for what seems to be two different dragons.

So, here am I asking. Is there any official evidence about where the tutorial take place and / or if two different "Dragon Gods" exist in the *Demon's Souls* world?